# Подписка на события геолокации и геокодирования в yandex map api 2.x

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как реализовать подписку на resolve/reject геолокации и/или геокодирования?

Цель: на нескольких моих картах требуется мониторинг успешных и неуспешных вызовов геолокации/геокодирования, вызываемых через ymaps.geolocation/ymaps.geocode.

Хотелось бы написать внешний обработчик вызываемых методов geolocation/geocode (для анализа поисковых запросов, а так же для мониторинга проблем геолокации/геокодирования). Можно, конечно, доработать код каждой моей карты в отдельности, но хотелось бы написать единый модуль для всех этих карт.

Comment: Вы можете вынести геолокацию в отдельную функцию и на конкретных картах просто вызывать эту функцию вместо геолокации напрямую. Этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Предлагаемый Вами вариант имелся в виду в последнем предложении стартового текста. К этому варианту склоняюсь, за отсутствием нужного в идеале. Но тогда придется дорабатывать все функции вызова геолокации/геокодирования на каждом экземпляре карт, которых много. А в идеале хотелось бы "сесть" на прослушивание вызовов этих функций и их ответов единым js-модулем, который запускался бы через seo-контейнер, установленный на все страницы наших сайтов, например, через GTM